# Confusion about arrays and string literals?

Tags: c++

I read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) but I did not really get what I searched for.

Why can I do this:

```
char duder[] = "duder";
```

When I cannot do this:

```
const char dusder[] = "dusder";
char nondusder[] = dusder;
```

So AFAIK the literals create constant unnamed array and why can't you then initialize an array to another array yourself if that is technically what is happening when doing `char duder[] = "duder";`?

Also, how can `duder` modify the string literal if it is constant?

If (even though I did search for this but did not find the answer to my question) there is a source that answers my questions, I would of course appreciate a link just as much as an answer :)

Comment: You shouldn't read the C reference page, but the C++ reference page instead: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks for the link. But it doesn't look like that it answers any of my questions, or am I blind?

Comment: It answers the question *"how can `duder` modify the string literal if it is constant?"*: *"If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`."* - Note that this is not the case in C - there modifying a string literal always leads to *undefined behavior*

Comment: @UnholySheep: You're mixing up two types here. `char duder[]` is _initialized_ with a string literal. It's a copy. It can't modify the string literal, because it doesn't point to the string literal. Now, it it was `char* duder = "duder";`, you'd have a point.

Comment: @MSalters please tell me how the linked question answers this? Like it does not explain why an array can be initialized to a string literal when that string literal technically is another array=

Comment: @NeiLee: As the first answer points out, that's just how the language is defined. It's inherited from C. As C++ normally uses `std::string`, fixing this inconsistency was never a priority.